# asp.net mvc - how to write ajax request in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, request

i would like to update follow div with ajax request written in javascript method.

asp.mvc view:

```
<div id="feed" onload="GetFeeds()">
            <span id="feeds" runat="server">
                    <%= Model.Feeds %>
            </span>
        </div>
```

what schould i do in javasript?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   // some AJAX Request with 'feed' Update, but HOW??
   document.getElementById('feed');

    function GetFeeds() { 
    // need to call method from HomeModel.cs GetAllFeeds()??
    // or i should to write hole methode here?
    }

</script>
```

it schould work without any controller action.
method for FeedUpdating is written in HomeModel.cs / GetAllFeeds() and it works. I need just call it from javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax( 
   url: 'http://localhost/feeds/feed1',
   type:'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) { 
         //Process data
   },
   error: function(error) { }
);
```

It does all the heavy lifting for you and is tested on many more browsers than you will be able to test on in your lifetime :)

Comment: is $.ajax in  <script type="text/javascript"> tags?

Comment: Yes. As said above you should read the documentation and look at jQuery examples. It really is easy. Make sure you look at the $(document).ready() part http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - it's important.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't mind then use [jquery $.get](http://api.jquery.com/get) function.

Comment: what is jquery, schould i install this seperatly?

Comment: MVC is kind of build with jQuery in mind (they jQuery with it, and in MVC3 the ajax stuff is build upon jQuery)

Comment: Knowledge of jQuery or any other kind of javascript framework is kind of a must in modern day website developed. Go to jquery.com and follow the tutorials.